# Did my query delete the entire table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I ran the query:

```
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE * FROM `1_cart_items` WHERE `forid`=?");
  $stmt->bindValue(1,$_SESSION['name'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
```

and I've appeared to delete the entire table, what have I done wrong that has caused this problem?

Comment: Did all rows have `forid` that == `$_SESSION['name']`?

Comment: Probably the `*` in `DELETE * FROM` which should have been `DELETE FROM`

Comment: how could it even delete since you have `delete * from ` and thats an invalid statement.

Comment: The `*` may have been causing the problem. I restored a backup and ran without the `*` and all seems fine. Although I'm unsure how the table might have dissapeared i may have something elsewhere wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite a short answer: no, your query did not cause your problem. Your query would have failed, as already said in the comments. The `*` will break the query, preventing it from deleting anything. Your problem must have originated somewhere else.